# Construct Dataframe with a column containing mixed Timestamp and pd.NaT values

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I'm using `pd.DataFrame.from_records()` to construct a DataFrame. My data contains a mix of pd.Timestamp and pd.NaT values to be mapped to a column.
When I call `from_records()` it either raises a `ValueError` or prints a message that the exception was ignored, depending on how that line of code was run (IPython console vs in a script).

```
In [20]: records = [
            {'id': 'Alice', 'bday': pd.Timestamp('1985-12-17 12:14:00')},
            {'id': 'Bob',   'bday': pd.NaT},
            {'id': 'Ella',  'bday': pd.NaT}]
In [21]: pd.DataFrame.from_records(records)
Exception ignored in: 'pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime.pydatetime_to_dtstruct'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\datetimes.py", line 2177, in objects_to_datetime64ns
    result, tz_parsed = tslib.array_to_datetime(
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
Exception ignored in: 'pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime.pydatetime_to_dtstruct'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\datetimes.py", line 2177, in objects_to_datetime64ns
    result, tz_parsed = tslib.array_to_datetime(
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
Out[21]: 
                        id                 bday
0                    Alice  1985-12-17 12:14:00
1                      Bob                  NaT
2                     Ella                  NaT
```

I found that if I replace the `pd.NaT` values with `pd.NA` in my data, the constructor runs fine.

```
In [22]: records = [
            {'id': 'Alice', 'bday': pd.Timestamp('1985-12-17 12:14:00')},
            {'id': 'Bob',   'bday': pd.NA},
            {'id': 'Ella',  'bday': pd.NA}]
In [23]: pd.DataFrame.from_records(records)
Out[23]: 
      id                 bday
0  Alice  1995-12-17 12:14:00
1    Bob                 <NA>
2   Ella                 <NA>
```

Is the best workaround to do these replacements in each dictionary before constructing the DataFrame? It seems like there should be something better.

Comment: Maybe you should upgrade your version of Pandas. It works for me (Pandas 2.0.2). You don't need to use `from_records`, you can simply use `pd.DataFrame(records)`

Comment: That would indeed be an elegant solution. This project has been running on pandas 1.5.2 as decreed by the anaconda dependency solver. I'm unsure if any of my dependencies would prevent an update to 2.0. I'll look into it. But I'd still like to find a solution for pandas 1.5.2 in case it doesn't work out.

Comment: A check via `conda update pandas` shows that I can only update to 1.5.3. So I'd still like to find a solution for pandas 1.5.2.

Comment: I tested with pandas 1.5.2, numpy 1.22.4 and python 3.9.16 and unfortunately I can't reproduce your error.

Comment: @Corralien I'm running numpy 1.23.5 and python 3.8.16, so I guess this issue was resolved in a python update. I was able to get the source data changed to use `pd.NA`, so I've worked around this instance of the problem.